# How can i get the post data in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

Server1.js

```
var data = querystring.stringify({
    imageName: reqImgName
  });

var options = {
              host: 'localhost',
              port: 4321,
              path: '/image',
              method: 'POST',
              headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'Content-Length': data.length
                }
            };
```

server2.js

```
http.createServer(function(req, res){
  var reqMethod=req.method;
  var request = url.parse(req.url, true);
  var pathName = request.pathname;
  console.log('Path name is '+pathName);
  if (reqMethod=='POST' && pathName == '/image') {

   //here i need my server1 data..how can i get here.
   } 

}).listen(4321);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var postData = '';
req.on('data', function(datum) {
  postData += datum;
});

req.on('end', function() {
  //read postData
});
```

You are not getting any post data because you're not sending any in server1.js. Try writing some data to the request body

```
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {

});


req.write('data=somedata');
```

Another way of debugging your server2 is to make a browser initiate a POST request to /image

Comment: i have tried this but..but im not getting anything in postData

Comment: thank you..previous i have sent like this req.write('data');thats y im not getting the image name..now working fine..

Answer (score 1):

Attach event listeners to the `data` and `end` events of `req`. `data` will give you chunks of data which you can incrementally process, and `end` will tell you when you've got everything.